# Magento 2 backend errors

Tags: magento2-dev-beta

I've just made a fresh installation of Magento 2 (Magento ver. 0.42.0-beta7). I've noticed that in the backend, the top navigation menu is not working (Sales, Products, Customers). Also when I try to switch the store view, I get a good number of javascript errors as follows:

[image]

I saw this behavior on both Chrome and Firefox.

Also, if I go to my Magento installation and go to pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US, I don't find the jquery folder. That explains the 404 errors for the javascript files.

Has anyone met this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure all folders are writable and the permissions were correct during installation?

Comment: I've tried re-installing giving 777 permissions but still to no avail. I've installed beta2 now and it's working.

Comment: Is this related to this issue reported on the Magento 2 official GitHub? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1016

Comment: Problem still exists `beta-19` four solid hours of clearing cache, fixing less issues, debugging script loading errors before I finally called it ... not looking good for the mage 2 team...`rm -rf /magento`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to a pre stable version of Magento 2: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 2):

Remove content of `pub/static/_requirejs/*` directory. I had similar issue after upgrading to beta7 and in my case it helped.

Maybe also delete content of following ones:

- `var/cache/*`
- `var/page_cache/*`
- `var/generation/*`